# OR Tools max number of destinations?

Tags: optimization, routes, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm using OR Tools to optimize more than 30 destinations, is there any max number using OR Tool?
Also what happen if I use timewindow, capacity constraints etc. Is there any limit?

I try with more than 25 detinations and seems to work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.